# How I can calculate distances between the two geopoints? and how to get my first initial geopoint is constant

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    double slatitude,slongitude ;
    float[] results;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 2000, 0, this);
         slatitude = location.getLatitude();
         slongitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);

        double elatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double elongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(elatitude, elongitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)); 
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + elatitude + ", Longitude:" + elongitude);
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try
        {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(elatitude, elongitude, 1);
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); 
        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
        String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
        String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); 

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), address+" "+city+" "+state+" "+country+" "+postalCode+""+knownName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
        try
        {
            Location.distanceBetween ( slatitude,  slongitude,  elatitude,  elongitude,  results);
            System.out.println(""+results+"km");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+results+"km",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able find distance between geo points when though I am using distanceBetween() here.

Comment: what issue u r getting when finding distance and what do you mean by First Initial geopoint in constant?

Comment: it doesn't showing distances value between geo points  and when we calling   slatitude = location.getLatitude();                                     slongitude =location.getLongitude(); in oncreate() the values getting overriden  with current geo points ??? it should be final so that i can calculate distances between start geo points and end geo points               Thanks in advances

Comment: doesn't showing means r u getting any kind of error or it is 0 or something ? pl explain a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get the distance:

```
    private String Distance(double latitude1, double longitude1, Double latitude2, Double longitude2) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    double earthRadius = 6371; //Kilometers
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(latitude2-latitude1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(longitude2-longitude1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(latitude2)) *
                    Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    float dist = (float) (earthRadius * c);


    String distance = df.format(dist);
    return (distance+" KM");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have few mistakes in your code.

When application is launched, in on create you are getting initial location using `getLastKnownLocation`, which you are immediately passing to `onLocationChanged` method. Now in `onLocationChanged` method you have distancebetween implementation, which is called before you assign values to your `slatitude` and `slongitude` variables which are being initialized after `onLocationChanged` call in onCreate. So here you can be getting the issue.

Next, Location.distanceBetween last argument is an array,  and to access what stored in this you have to specify index 0, 1, 2, so your code

```
System.out.println(""+results+"km");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+results+"km",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

should be

```
System.out.println(""+results[0]+"km");
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+results[0]+"km",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Secondly the result returned in Location.distanceBetween is in meters and not kilometers as per [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]))

Another options for you is, you can use [location.distanceTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) methods of location class as below

```
Location startLocation = <your start location>
Location destinationLocation = <one you get in onLocationChanged method>

//This too returns distance in meters and not kilometers
float distance = startLocation.distanceTo (destinationLocation);
```

Comment: if my answer solved your issue then pl accept the answer and upvote. :)